# Can't set the execution policy to allow me to execute a script in a Visual Studio post build event

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to use the [Powershell Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 to structure my script modules and their tests, and run my own custom build script when Visual Studio builds the project.

I have a powershell script that I wrote that will build the module manifest files for me. I can call this script from my CI system or from my developer machine's prompt very easily. I want to call that script as a Post-build event so that I can rebuild the module the way I want, because I do not want to have to manually track/update some of the manifest properties.

So in my project properties, I add a event with the following:
`& 'C:\Path\To\My\Modules\Build-ALLModules.ps1' -moduleName 'MyModule.psm1'`

My build succeeds, but in the output log I get:

`File C:\Path\To\My\Modules\Build-ALLModules.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.`

I have read `about_Execution_Policies` before, so I try to set the execution policy in the post build event step right before I run my script:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force; & 'C:\Path\To\My\Modules\Build-ALLModules.ps1' -moduleName 'MyModule.psm1'`

Which fails with a hard error that prevents the build:

`"Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted; & 'C:\Path\To\My\Modules\Build-ALLModules.ps1' -moduleName 'MyModule.psm1'" is an invalid value for the "Command" parameter of the "RunPowerShellCommand" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".`

I am not exactly sure of how to accomplish this now. I have been able to run PS scripts from a Visual Studio build by running the powershell executable as a build event, and then I can specify `–ExecutionPolicy Bypass` and either run an arbitrary command or a script file. 
Powershell Project:
[image]